# Data not persisting to sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a Dashboard ViewController that checks if a database exists and if it doesn't then it sends the user to a login ViewController where then the database is created. The user then has to sign in and their password and username is saved into the SQLite database. Then they are sent to the dashboard ViewController. The problem with this is once the user does sign in and are sent back to the dashboard ViewController they are rejected and sent back to the login ViewController. I don't know if the information isn't being saved into the database or what is happening But here is my Login m file

```
#import "LoginView.h"
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "SignupView.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface LoginView ()

@end

@implementation LoginView


@synthesize txtPassword;
@synthesize txtUsername;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"username.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &usernameDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERNAME (USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(usernameDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {

            }

            sqlite3_close(usernameDB);

        } else {

        }
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertView show];
}

- (IBAction)signupButton:(id)sender {
    SignupView *myView = [[SignupView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignupView" bundle:nil];
    [myView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; //you can change the way it is presented
    [myView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical]; //you can change the animation
    [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:nil]; //show the modal view

}

- (IBAction)backgroundClicked:(id)sender {
    [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {


    @try {

        if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/ios_login/index.php"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%d",success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    [self saveData];

                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
}

-(void)saveData{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &usernameDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO USERNAME (username, password) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\")", txtUsername.text, txtPassword.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(usernameDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(usernameDB);

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    }
}

@end
```

Here is my dashboard M

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LoginView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self checkIfLogged];

}

- (void) checkIfLogged
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &usernameDB) == SQLITE_OK) //second if
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM username"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(usernameDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {//match found



            } else {// match not found

                LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
                [loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
                [loginView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
                [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];



            }//end else
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);


        }//end second if
        else{

            LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
            [loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
            [loginView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
            [self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        sqlite3_close(usernameDB);

    }//end first IF
   }//end checkIfLogged

@end
```

I have a feeling the information isn't being saved into the database but I don't know why. The information should be saved in the login view under saveData()

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are not displaying any error or logging any message if any of your SQLite calls fail. Thus, you are making it very difficult for yourself to identify any issues. You should log some message if the SQLite call fails, e.g., instead of:

   ```
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(usernameDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
   if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
   {

   }
   ```

   you should do:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(usernameDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
       sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
       return;
   }

   if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
   }
   ```

   You should do this sort of logging for *every* SQLite function called. This not only will inform you during development if there is an issue, but more importantly, the `sqlite3_errmsg` function will tell you what the issue is.

   There's little benefit in checking your SQLite return codes if you don't report the error if it happens. Doing this, you can identify precisely where it's going wrong. The problem will probably become self-evident at that point, but if not, let us know.
2. Once you get this issue behind you, you should look at your network request. You really should be doing your network request asynchronously (e.g. `sendAsynchronousRequest`), not synchronously. You never should do synchronous requests on the main queue. (See [Avoid Synchronous Networking Calls on the Main Thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH4-SW9).)
3. Also unrelated, but you should not be building your SQL using `stringWithFormat`. What if the password had a quotation mark in it? At best, your SQLite call would fail if the user accidentally entered something with a quotation mark. Worse, you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

   You should be using `?` placeholders in your SQL, and then bind values to those placeholders with, for example, `sqlite3_bind_text`:

   ```
   const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO USERNAME (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(usernameDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
       sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
       return;
   }

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(insert_stmt, 1, [txtUsername.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert bind user failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
       return;
   }

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(insert_stmt, 2, [txtPassword.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert bind password failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
       return;
   }

   if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
   {
       NSLog(@"%s: insert step failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(usernameDB));
       sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
       return;
   }

   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   sqlite3_close(usernameDB);
   ```
4. Also, you should be percent escaping the username and password parameters you're passing in your network request. What if the password had an ampersand or plus sign in it? (An ampersand would terminate the password prematurely. The plus would be converted to a space.)

   Some will suggest using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, but you actually have to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, which gives you a little control. So, you might define a method:

   ```
   - (NSString *)stringForPostParameterValue:(NSString *)string
   {

       NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=+$,",
                                                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
       return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
   }
   ```

   So, instead of:

   ```
   NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
   ```

   You would then:

   ```
   NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", [self stringForPostParameterValue:[txtUsername text]], [self stringForPostParameterValue:[txtPassword text]]];
   ```

   If you test your current code with a password that contains, for example a `+` or `&` in it, and you'll see why you have to do something like the above.
5. You obviously shouldn't be transmitting/storing passwords in clear text at all. But that's a bigger topic.

Comment: I'd also point out that hand-writing SQL and direct use of the SQLite API is both extremely difficult and typically unnecessary. At least use a wrapper (like FMDB) or, better yet, embrace Core Data.  If you are going to use SQLite, first know that it is hard and, secondly, that you *must handle every single possible result code from any given SQLite API call*.  If you don't handle every single error appropriately, you are guaranteed to produce an app that loses data.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is excellent if doing SQLite code, and Core Data is often altogether preferable.